# vb6 change reference path

Tags: vb6, reference

I am using Visual Basic 6.

There are some component references in my project. Components are registered with Windows using "regsvr32".
So, I have added `.ocx` from the installation directory to Components.

Let say `C:\Program Files\Install Dir\`. But, When I see References `(.oca)` for the control,  VB automatically taking path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98` and I can see `.oca` files are getting copied.

But, I want to use References from the Install dir only. I tried removing or updating, It says `Can't remove control or reference;In use`

I have already tried editing `.vbp` in editor but It does not show `.oca` Reference path not even default `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveX DLLs and OCXs install as *shared libraries* by design.  For this reason you almost never want to install them into a private folder like your `C:\Program Files\Install Dir\` unless they are truly private in the sense of being parts of your application that other code should not use.

More generic "utility" libraries such as those provided by Microsoft, 3rd parties, or even those you develop yourself normally install in developer mode by including both design-time licenses (when licensed) and more relevantly here .DEP files.  Part of the information contained in such .DEP files is *where the library is meant to be installed.*  In some cases this is System32, in others it is a folder under Common Files, etc.

Now if you truly want a private copy of a DLL or OCX there is a mechanism for that.  These are called *isolated assemblies* and they replaced the earlier, problematic .local mechanism in Win2K.

Those .OCA files are something else entirely and you should not try to reference them or deploy them.

But it is hard to tell what you are really after.  A message like:

> Can't remove control or reference;In use.

.. is a design-time issue entirely unrelated to the rest of your question.

I'm just not sure what you are trying to do.  It sounds like you are trying to re-use libraries private to some other application.